# Extracting Data from HTML emails using Python

Tags: python, email

I'm very new to python. And I want to extract data from certain fields from an HTML email that is received on an Exchange server. All the emails come from the same email id and have the same format. I want to extract 3 rows out of it, Client_Name, Client_Phone, and Client_Address. I receive 20 emails a day. And want to export the data of every new email into .csv or .xls

How do i go about it? I stuck at connecting to an exchange server in the very beginning.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I don't use Exchange  but normally you have to connect using IMAP or POP3 protocol (modules `poplib` or `imaplib`), get mail and use normal string manipulation, or get HTML from mail and use HTML parser (modules `html.parser`, `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Exchange and maybe there are special modules for Exchange but normally you have to connect to server using IMAP or POP3 protocol ([poplib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/poplib.html) or [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html)), get mail ([email](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.html)) and use normal string manipulation, or get HTML from mail and use HTML parser ([html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.parser.html), [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)). Finally you have to save it in CSV ([csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)) or in xls (??? - I prefer CSV)

---

**EDIT:** simple google question "python exchange": [PyExchange](https://pyexchange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)